# Select multiple columns from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to select three columns (username, browser and browser version) from a database but when I use the first variable I get multiple results for each user. I only want each user once with the browser he uses. With the second variable, I get the user once but without the browser.

```
var browserUser = db.Tracking.Include(t => t.Users).ToList();
var browserUserFiltered = browserUser.GroupBy(x => x.userIdFk).Select(g => g.First());
```

---

Screenshot of the actual output
[image]

---

Database model
[image]

Comment: Use select many

var browserUserFiltered = browserUser.GroupBy(x => x.userIdFk).SelectMany(g => g.First());

Comment: Please share columns of Tracking, Users table and desired output

Comment: I added the database model. Me desired output is like 
user1, Chrome, Version xxx --> this is in my database and i want to display this on my asp.net page in a table.

Comment: @SmightyM8 ASP.NET is a web stack, not an ORM or data access techonlogy. The code does what you told it to do - load *all* tracking rows and *all* related users. If you wanted users with browsers you should start from `db.Users` and any relevant tracking rows.

Comment: Thank you, now i get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have sequences of `Users` and `Trackings`. Every `User` has zero or more `Trackings`, every `Tracking` belongs to exactly one `User`, using a foreign key `UserIdFk`. A straight forward one-to-many relations.

```
User                Tracking
Id | Name           Id | UserIdFk | <other properties>
 1 | Jan            10 |    1     | A
 2 | Piert          11 |    1     | B
                    12 |    2     | C

var browserUser = db.Tracking.Include(t => t.Users).ToList();
```

Result: a sequence of 3 Trackings, each with their User

```
Tracking: Id = 10, UserIdFk = 1; User: Id = 1; Name = Jan
Tracking: Id = 11, UserIdFk = 1; User: Id = 1; Name = Jan
Tracking: Id = 12, UserIdFk = 2; User: Id = 2, Name = Piert
```

Do the GroupBy:

```
var browserUserFiltered = browserUser.GroupBy(x => x.userIdFk)
```

Result: a sequence of 2 IGrouping

```
Group Key: 1; Elements:
      Tracking: Id = 10, UserIdFk = 1; User: Id = 1; Name = Jan
      Tracking: Id = 11, UserIdFk = 1; User: Id = 1; Name = Jan
Group Key: 2; Elements:
      Tracking: Id = 12, UserIdFk = 2; User: Id = 2, Name = Piert
```

Continue after the GroupBy:

```
.Select(g => g.First());
```

Result: a sequence of two items, one item per group:

```
Tracking: Id = 10, UserIdFk = 1; User: Id = 1; Name = Jan
Tracking: Id = 12, UserIdFk = 2; User: Id = 2, Name = Piert
```

**Question: Why do you think there would be only one item in your result?**

---

In a one-to-many you can go two ways:

- Get Users with their Trackings, which means that internally a Group-Join is done. Every User is transferred to your process exactly once. Users without Tracking data are also in your result.
- Get Trackings, each with its User. Internally an inner join is done. If a user has more than one Tracking, the the same user data is sent more than once. Users without any tracking data is not mentioned at all.

It is up to you to decide what you want.

### Use Select instead of Include

One of the slower parts of database queries is the transport of the selected data to your process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of selected data.

If User 4 has 1000 Trackings, then every Tracking will have a foreign key UserId with a value equal to 4. If you use Include to select the data the same foreign key value will be sent 1000 times, while you already know that it equals the value of the User's primary key: 4. What a waste!

> When querying data, always use Select and select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only use Include if you plan to update the included item.

So to fetch some Users with (some of their) trackings, execute the following query:

```
var result = dbContext.Users
    .Where(user => ...)              // only if you don't want all Users
    .Select(user => new
    {
        // Select only the User data you actually plan to use
        Id = user.Id,
        Name = user.Name,
        ...

        Trackings = user.Trackings
            .Where(tracking => tracking.Date >= startDate) // only if you don't want all Trackings
            .Select(tracking => new
            {
                 // again: select only the properties you plan to use
                 Id = tracking.Id,
                 Name = tracking.Name,
                 ...
                 // not needed, you know the value: UserId = tracking.UserId
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I already solved it with a solution which is similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the browser and browserVersion by FirstOrDefault:

```
var browserUserFiltered = browserUser.GroupBy(x => x.userIdFk).Select(g => new { 
username= g.FirstOrDefault().username,
browser= g.FirstOrDefault().browser,
browserVersion= g.FirstOrDefault().browserVersion,
});
```

Comment: I tried this but i get an error with the type. The model element passed to the dictionary has the type "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,WebApp.Models.Tracking],<>f__AnonymousType1`3[WebApp.Models.Users,System.String,System.String]]". However, this dictionary requires a model element of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApp.Models.Tracking]".

Answer (score 0):

Install morelinq from npm, then use `users.DistinctBy(u=>userId).ToList()`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/